# What's with allocator in vector?

Tags: c++, allocator, istream-iterator

```
vector<int> data(istream_iterator<int>(cin),
istream_iterator<int>{});   cout<<"Size is : " << data.size() << endl; //compile success

vector<int> data1(istream_iterator<int>(cin),
std::allocator<int>{});   cout<<"Size is : " << data1.size() << endl; //compile failure
```

---

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::vector(std::istream_iterator<int>, std::allocator<int>)’    vector<int> data1(istream_iterator<int>(cin), std::allocator<int>{});
```

Why is the first statement fine but second? Doesn't the vector take `int` type allocator in this case? I am experimenting with `allocator`s.

Comment: "_compile failure_" What is the compilation error?

Comment: Because the second one doesn't make sense?  What does it mean to create a vector from a beginning iterator and an allocator?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Isn't the first also same. Begining iterator and then allocator.

Comment: Because there is a constructor that take 2 iterators but there isn't one that take 1 iterator and 1 alloator. [std::vector<T,Allocator>::vector - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: `istream_iterator<int>{}` represents the matching end iterator for `istream_iterator<int>(cin)` as begin iterator. (For input iterators, it's valid to use a default constructed (aka. singular iterator) as end iterator - as I recently learnt.)

Comment: @InQusitive `istream_iterator<int>{}` is **not** an allocator.  It's a sentinel iterator (end iterator for a stream)

Comment: there is no allocator in the first

Comment: @InQusitive "_Isn't the first also same. Begining iterator and then allocator_" No, first one doesn't contain any reference to any allocator. It references only `istream_iterator`.

Comment: @MikeCAT: If second argument is allocator for a vector, why is giving a non allocator is working in first statement?

Comment: The allocator is a default argument. It doesn't need to be given explicitly. It's this constructor `template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` which is used.

Comment: @InQusitive Because there is an overload that takes two iterators but none that takes an iterator and an allocator?

Comment: there are several overloads of the constructor. In the first line you call the one that takes two iterators. In the second line there is no matching overload

Comment: @InQusitive Note that there are a lot of [overloads for the constructor for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).  None of those take a single allocator and an allocator.

Comment: @Scheff : Are you referring first statement? I copied it from "Using The C++ Standard Template Library" book.

Comment: with some practice we could do this even more synced :P

Comment: @InQusitive Yes, my first comment referred to your first snippet. (and I didn't say that there is something wrong with it - just explained it a bit)

Comment: @Scheff : When I remove the end iterator from the first statement, why does the code say the "data" is of non class type for .size method for data.size()? But data creation has no compile issues.

Comment: If you remove the end iterator from the first statement, it tries to use one of the numerous other (but non-matching) constructors. You need the constructor for a range given by begin and end iterator and none of them is provided with a default argument (as this wouldn't make much sense). So, you always have to give both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the first statement fine

Because vector has a constructor that accepts two iterators (and an allocator with default argument). Those iterators represent beginning and end of an input range.

> but second [is not]?

Because vector doesn't have a constructor that accepts a single iterator and an allocator.

Comment: [Not referring my code] Why doesn't vector have single iterator with allocator but is having two iterator with allocator?

Comment: @InQusitive Because a single iterator cannot represent a range. How could the constructor know how many elements to read from the iterator?